# Servicestack.Redis PooledClient()

Tags: c#-4.0, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

```
public class TransporterServicesAppHost : AppHostBase
{

    public TransporterServicesAppHost() : base("TServices", typeof(OTService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { ServiceStackHandlerFactoryPath = "api" });
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager());
        container.Register<IRepository>(c => new Repository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>));
    }
}
```

Am Unable to Register Repository , am getting error "can not convert method group" to "IRedisClientsManager" .

sorry , its look like newbie issue ,but can some one help.?

Comment: Please post the code you're using that repro's the issue.

Comment: hi @mythz , do u need some more info..? . Its strange that same code for a demo working well, but for this code its taking up random number.

Comment: I'd need code that provides a [minimal verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue in order to be able to identify what it is. If you have code that I can run that reproduces the issue I'll be able to run it locally and identify what the issue is.

Comment: If you can't tell why the same code is producing different results try [enable debug logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging) to see if there are any errors being logged.

Comment: That's an awesome tip,  I will try out.

Comment: @mythz am encountering this problem also , so edited.could you tell wats wrong please.

Comment: Your resolve method needs (), otherwise it treats it as a method group which is invalid here.

Comment: You are awesome bro:)